# How to verify SSL in Grails application running on tomcat?

Tags: ssl, tomcat6, ssl-certificate

I am able to run Grails application on tomcat using SSL but I am not sure how to verify that it is running properly with SSL.

I am able to do following things (I am using grails security)...

1. Created Self Signed SSL certification
2. Able to configure same certification with tomcat(updated server.xml)
3. Able to run application using https in browser(All features are running 
   properly with https url, I did not updated web.xml of war).

**Problem**: I am able to see logged in user's user credentials using Fiddler.

So I am not sure that I did correct configure of SSL or I did some mistake.

**Can anyone suggest me how to verify that the data in traveling in encrypted form ??**

Comment: I have used Acunetix tool for security auditing and it confirms Eric point, my mean user name and password is not in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've enabled HTTPS decryption in Fiddler (Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS), then being able to see the credentials is expected. If you *haven't* enabled HTTPS decryption in Fiddler, then you are not using HTTPS properly.

Comment: Thanks EricLaw :)
Yes, I have enabled HTTPS decryption in fiddler but without that I am not able to capture data...
Please also suggest me how to capture data without above setting... 
Thanks in Advance  :)